# How to implement a navigation button in JSF 2.0 that doesnt do any validations of anything on the current page?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to implement a navigation button that takes the user to another page. I have no desire or need for any validations to run nor for the model to be updated, etc. I have implemented this as an ajaxified client-side redirect (note, I am using Primefaces 3.2).

It works-- *but is this the best way to do this?*

Navigating from the "onePage.xhtml" to the "anotherPage.xhtml"

```
onePage.xhtml:
...
<p:commandButton value="Navigate to Another Page" 
                 process="@this"/>
                 action="anotherPage?faces-redirect=true" 

...
```

Note, I have tried using immediate="true", however Apply Request Values phase still runs, which results in a NPE for me in a getter in my managed bean (as I no longer have the data that my getter needs).

Comment: I've hit a similar problem. In my case, I'm trying to invoke an action from a button that does not need any context on the rendered page. However, any `commandButton`, including `<p:commandButton>`, ajax or not, is causing the `<p:dataTable>` that was also rendered to take action during the Update Model Values phase (for no good reason that I can find). Since the backing data is gone (I don't need it past rendering), I get a NullPointerException. This does not happen with `<h:dataTable>`, only the Primefaces dataTable.

Comment: If you haven't already, you may want to create a new Stack Overflow question as your question is more specific this this one (i.e. problem with p:dataTable). You can always reference back to this question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`<h:button>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) or [`<p:button>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button.jsf). It sends a normal GET request. There's really no need for a POST-Redirect-GET request if it's just page-to-page navigation.

```
<h:button value="Navigate to Another Page" outcome="anotherPage" />
```

For the PrimeFaces look'n'feel, just replace `h:` by `p:`. Note that this component doesn't require a [`<h:form>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/form.html). The link equivalent is the [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) (for which there's no PrimeFaces equivalent, there's anyway nothing which needs to be restyled).

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Answer (score 1):

Set attribute `immediate` to `true` on commandButton, this will skip all validations, conversions or updates. Attributes causes JSF lifecycle to jump from Apply request values phase directly to Render Response phase.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me -- Apply Request Values phase still runs, which results in a NPE for me in a getter in my managed bean (as I no longer have data that my getter needs).